# What does the "nr_order" column in the imdbpy "cast_info" table represent?

Tags: python, mysql, imdb, imdbpy

I can't find any useful explanation by googling, and I don't see anything in the IMDB database files.

What is the meaning of `nr_order` in `cast_info`?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a number to indicate the billing position in the credits.

It's defined [here](https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/src/c5b5454b544cab9b650ed1e09b2b958134c4473e/imdb/parser/sql/dbschema.py?at=default#cl-313) in the db schema.

[This](https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy/src/c5b5454b544cab9b650ed1e09b2b958134c4473e/bin/imdbpy2sql.py?at=default#cl-1569) shows where the value will be filled up.

Looking in the actresses.list.gz file I found this at the top:

```
"xxxxx"        = a television series
"xxxxx" (mini) = a television mini-series
[xxxxx]        = character name
<xx>           = number to indicate billing position in credits
(TV)           = TV movie, or made for cable movie
(V)            = made for video movie (this category does NOT include TV 
                 episodes repackaged for video, guest appearances in 
                 variety/comedy specials released on video, or 
                 self-help/physical fitness videos)
```

Looks like there wasn't any useful documentation for it in IMDbPY either.